# When typing, accidentally writing a phonetically similar word instead of the intended one - is there a name for this? Any explanation?

Tags: language, motor, language-processing, executive-function

Question:

Is there a scientific term for the following phenomenon, or, if not, what would be a possible explanation (e.g. certain brain structures not working as smoothly together, as required for the task)?
What would be some related publications, I could read to get a better understanding?
Note that I am not a neuroscientist, but a somewhat scientifically literate layman.

Phenomenon:

It often happens to me, that, when typing on a keyboard, I accidentally write a different but phonetically similar word instead of the one I intend to write, even when I am certain about the correct spelling. Examples: bear -> bare, here -> hear, heart -> hard

When proof-reading, I will usually catch those mistakes, but only if I consciously focus on spelling, rather than on improving my wording.
I usually have an "inner voice" when reading or typing, so I would assume, this happens because similar words are associated simultaneously when my inner voice reads the text and there is an error when translating this into the motor activity.
Note that I do type "semi-consciously" in the sense that the keys are pressed without conscious thought or letter-seeking, but that I have never learned typing systematically and use a rather unorthodox and chaotic four finger technique at a moderate speed of ~200cpm. I could not describe where most letters are on a standard keyboard, but will hit them without thought when typing actual sentences. However, I am able to type blindly only for a few words at once, before I have to slow down and check my fingers' positions.
I believe above details might be relevant, as that typing style might require a lot of cognitive capacity, allowing for misassociations to occur.

Comment: Happens to me too, I think it maybe an extension of dyslexia

Comment: Search for phonetic substitution